# Merge Sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mergesort

Can anybody please tell what am I doing wrong in my Merge-Sort

```
def print_array(a)
  print a
  print "\n\n"
end

#Merge-Sort code starts Here.
def merge_sort(a)
  if a.size < 2
    return a
  end

  middle = (a.length / 2).to_i
  left = a.slice(0, middle)
  right = a.slice(middle, a.size)

  merge_sort(left)
  merge_sort(right)

  a = merge(left, right)
end

def merge(left, right) 
  result = []

  while left.length > 0 || right.length > 0
    if left.length > 0 && right.length > 0
      if left[0] <= right[0]
        result << left.slice!(0)
      else
        result << right.slice!(0)
      end
    elsif left.length > 0
      result.concat left.slice!(0..left.length-1)
    elsif right.length > 0
      result.concat right.slice!(0..right.length-1)
    end
  end

  result  
end

a = [ 3, 2, 1 ]
print_array(a)

a = merge_sort(a)
print_array(a)
```

Basically, What I know is that when it comes time to Merge [2] and [1], that happens correctly (ie. [1, 2] is returned) , but for the previous step of the Recursion as it unwinds, it comes back (or doesn't come back) as **[1, 2]** but as **[2, 1]**, ie.

*Previous step*
-> left = [3]
-> right = [2, 1] #This is the value of right from recursion instead of [1, 2]

I don't know how to fix this, and it's driving me crazy, Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines:

```
merge_sort(left) 
merge_sort(right)
```

should be:

```
left = merge_sort(left) 
right = merge_sort(right)
```

Since your merge sort is not sorting in place, you need to assign the result back to the variables.

Comment: Wow, that's weird, I thought I had tried that! but anyways, good answer!